# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined on submit

Tags: reactjs, firebase

im  trying to make search function with friebase but am getting an error saing cannot read property push of undefined. Its happening when i click on search button , am supposed to get redirected to search result compoent but nothing is happening. Any help is greatly appreiceated! thanks !!!!

NavBar.js

```
 import React from "react";
    import {
      Collapse,
      Navbar,
      NavbarToggler,
      NavbarBrand,
      Nav,
      Button,
      NavItem,
      NavLink,
      UncontrolledDropdown,
      DropdownToggle,
      DropdownMenu,
      DropdownItem
    } from "reactstrap";
    import { Redirect, Link } from "react-router-dom";
    import Searchresults from "./searchresults";

    import app from "../config/dev";
    import { Route, withRouter } from "react-router";

    export default class NavigatioBar extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          authenticated: false,


currentUser: null,
      redirect: false,
      email: "",
      name: "",

      isOpen: false
    };
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    this.signout = this.signout.bind(this);
  }
  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
    });
  }

  signout() {
    app
      .auth()
      .signOut()
      .then(user => {
        this.setState({ redirect: true });
      });
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    app.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.setState({
          currentUser: user,
          email: user.email,
          authenticated: true
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          currentUser: null,
          authenticated: false
        });
      }
    });
  }
  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.history.push(`/champ/${this.state.name}`);
  };
  render() {
    let content = null;
    if (content !== null) {
      <Searchresults name={this.state.name} />;
    } else {
      <p> h </p>;
    }
    let searchMake = ["Ahri", "Zed", "Malphite", "Talon", "Velkoz", "Jax"];
    let names = searchMake.map((name, i) => {
      return (
        <option key={i} value={name}>
          {name}
        </option>
      );
    });
    const { redirect } = this.state;
    if (redirect) {
      return <Redirect to="/signout" />;
    }
    const authenticated = this.state.authenticated;
    return (
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        &#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;
        <Link to="/">
          <a className="navbar-brand" href="/">
            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSW4ZhCsXYeyhMYuaOZTGVq2VkeAW9gvDcgOfdPZ1B0WbYaBvR4" />
          </a>
        </Link>
        <button
          className="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#navbarNavDropdown"

Lin  aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span className="navbar-toggler-icon" />
        </button>
        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
          <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
            <li className="nav-item active">
              &#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;
              <a className="nav-link" href="#">
                <Link to="/">
                  Champs <span className="sr-only">(current)</span>
                </Link>
              </a>
              &#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;
            </li>
            {authenticated ? (
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a className="nav-link" onClick={this.signout}>
                  signout
                </a>
              </li>
            ) : (
              <li className="nav-item">
                &#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;
                <Link to="/login" className="nav-link">
                  {" "}
                  Login{" "}
                </Link>{" "}
                &#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;
                <Link to="/signup" className="nav-link">
                  {" "}
                  signup{" "}
                </Link>
              </li>
            )}
          </ul>
          <form
            onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
            className="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0"
            id="crap"
          >
            <div className="col-3">
              <select
                className="form-control"
                value={this.state.name}
                onChange={e => this.setState({ name: e.target.value })}
              >
                <option value="" disabled selected>
                  Champ
                </option>
                {names}
              </select>
            </div>
            <div className="col-3">
              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success btn-block">
                Search
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        {content}
      </nav>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change

```
export default class NavigatioBar extends React.Component {
    // ...
}
```

to

```
class NavigatioBar extends React.Component {
    // ...
}
export default withRouter(NavigatioBar);
```

otherwise when you do

```
this.props.history.push(`/champ/${this.state.name}`);`
```

`this.props.history` will be undefined, which is why you get that error.